# How do I run a python file that is read into a std::string using PyRun

Tags: c++, python

I am embedding Python into my C++ program, and have used PyRun_SimpleString quite effectively but now am having trouble.

What I have done is loaded a python.py file a std::string but am now having troubles running it. PyRun_SimpleFileEx didn't seem to do the trick either so some help would be great!

```
    std::string content;
    if(!ail::read_file(python_script, content))
    {
        error("Failed to load Python script \"" + python_script + "\"");
        return false;
    }

    if(prompt_mode)
        initialise_console();

    content = ail::replace_string(content, "\r", "");

    Py_Initialize();
    initialise_module();

    std::string script_directory;
    if(get_base_name(python_script, script_directory))
        PyRun_SimpleString(("import sys\nsys.path.append('" + script_directory + "')\n").c_str());

        write_line("Script dir: " + script_directory);
        ////-python_script H:\\CRAW\\craw\\script\\craw.py
        //content.c_str()

    //FILE *fp;
    //fp = fopen("H:\\CRAW\\craw\\script\\craw.py", "r");

    //PyRun_SimpleFileEx(fp, "craw.py", 1);
    if(PyRun_SimpleString(content.c_str()) != 0)
    {
        write_line("The main Python script contained errors.");
        return false;
    }

    //PyRun_SimpleString(("execfile('" + ail::replace_string(python_script, "\\", "\\\\") + "')").c_str());

    return true;
```

Comment: Posting a small sample of your code so we know what you're doing would be great!

Comment: Provide your troublesome code in question

Comment: If you need a char pointer (I don't know how PyRun works), the solution may be as simple as calling the c_str method of std::strings.

Comment: I'd say the 'embedded' tag doesn't belong here as it's meant to serve for topics about embedded systems (i.e. ARM processors), not embedding scripting languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using a string vector and reading each line of the file into the vector, then executing each one using PyRun_SimpleString.

Here's the finished code, no error checking though.
        std::vector string_vector;
        std::string content;
        if(python_script.empty())
            return true;

```
    ail::read_lines(python_script, string_vector);

    if(!ail::read_file(python_script, content))
    {
        error("Failed to load Python script \"" + python_script + "\"");
        return false;
    }

    if(prompt_mode)
        initialise_console();

    content = ail::replace_string(content, "\r", "");

    Py_Initialize();
    initialise_module();

    std::string script_directory;
    if(get_base_name(python_script, script_directory))
        PyRun_SimpleString(("import sys\nsys.path.append('" + script_directory + "')\n").c_str());

    for(int i = 0; i < string_vector.size(); i++)
    {
        string_vector[i] = ail::replace_string(string_vector[i], "\r", "");
        PyRun_SimpleString(string_vector[i].c_str());
    }

    return true;
```