# passing parameter in python script using "PyRun_SimpleString(pythonScript.py)"

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run a python file that is read into a std::string using PyRun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028681/how-do-i-run-a-python-file-that-is-read-into-a-stdstring-using-pyrun)

i am very new to python.
m invoking python script from C++ code and i want to pass one string in python script(pythonScript.py) and use it inside pythonScript.py. So please let me know asap how can i achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried googling this asap?

Comment: yeah...i have tried but i didnt get proper soln, so only i posted here...i think people here are more experienced then google..:)